# How to use streams in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, java-stream

I want to manipulate arrays in JS in a similar fashion with [Java Streams](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/).

So

```
arr.map().map().map()
```

Will do only one iteration.

How can I achieve that without a library?

Comment: Do you mean it's only reaching the first `map` function, or it's not iterating through nested array values?

Comment: I want to achieve something like this https://winterbe.github.io/streamjs/ . Currently every array.map() iterate on the whole array and creates a new one, then again and again.

Comment: `.map()` is without a lib, what do you want to do ?

Comment: @azro make it work in a lazy fashion as java streams or winterbe streamjs.

Comment: Because wht is the probelm with chaining multiple map ?

Comment: I want to all .map() operations to evaluated together, not do a reiteration on every map. Efficiency.

Comment: @azro For the obvious reason—streaming is significantly more efficient, which can matter under some circumstances.

Comment: To implement this without a library you’d follow the same patterns as the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to LINQ in DotNet. And there are a lot of library that do that for you already.

You might want to check out linq.js. It follows the .NET lambda syntax and looks to be well integrated in a Microsoft environment.

[LINQ for JavaScript -](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

**Pros**

- Implements all .NET 4.0 methods Complete lazy evaluation Full
- IntelliSense support for VisualStudio Supports jQuery Supports
- Windows Script Host Binding for Reactive Extensions for
- JavaScript(RxJS) and IntelliSense Generator NuGet install support
- Updated recently (last release Jan 2011) Syntax conforms to lambda
- syntax in C#

**Cons**

- The linq.js library is a little large.
- If you are already using jQuery or other js library, the most commonly used functionality is probably already available. See especially jQuery's filter, and 'Any' methods.

Others Similarly Library are:

- You can also check [Rx for Javascript](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Introducing-RxJS-Reactive-Extensions-for-JavaScript/)
- For a very nice, complete set of functional list operations, try: http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/
- For more information on how to use just javascript to manipute your list, Please check https://gist.github.com/DanDiplo/30528387da41332ff22b